# An Homage to "The World's Hardest Riddle"

Tags: riddle, word, english

This is an homage to [The World's Hardest Riddle](https://www.riddles.com/archives/5831).
This riddle will make more sense if you check it out first.

I apparently am not smarter than a kindergartener, but here's my version of the riddle to match the answer I had guessed.

> I show polar bears white
> and I make you wanna try.
>
> I make guys have to pee,
> and girls have to pee too.
>
> I make celebrities look stupid
> and I make normal people cool.
>
> Part of me turns pancakes brown
> and makes your champagne bubble.
>
> If you're mean to me I'll pop.
> If you smell too much you'll drop.
>
> Can you guess THIS riddle?

The format is made to reflect the original, but each line should refer back to a single word.

**What is the word?**

Comment: Let me guess... No??

Comment: @Stevo Lol. Well due to frustration with the ridiculousness of the original riddle, mine actually does have a (real) answer.

Comment: What I would give to be kindergartener again for a moment . . .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it possibly

> Coke?

*I show polar bears white
and I make you wanna try.*

> The [Coca-cola commercial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coca-Cola_polar_bears) *shows* polar bears white and make you wanna try to drink the coke.

*I make guys have to pee,
and girls have to pee too.*

> When drinking coke people need to pee after some time

*I make celebrities look stupid
and I make normal people cool.*

> Coke (as in cocaine) makes celebrities look stupid if they get caught on film/photo doing something outrageous. And it makes normal ppl "cool", more confident/outgoing in terms of socializing (unless they behave outrageous too ofc)

*Part of me turns pancakes brown
and makes your champagne bubble*

> The first two letters C(carbon) and O(oxygen) (along with amino acids) is what causes the food to become brown via a chemical reaction called [Maillard reaction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maillard_reaction) and the same two letters C(carbon) and O(oxygen) (along with hydrogen) is also what causes champagne bubbles, [Carbonic acid](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonic_acid#:%7E:text=In%20chemistry%2C%20carbonic%20acid%20is,H%202CO%203.)

*If you're mean to me I'll pop.
If you smell too much you'll drop.*

> By opening a can of coke, you "broke" it (and therefore "mean" to it) and hear the classical pop. If you smell too much of the gas from a can of coke you can feel dizzy. Too much carbon dioxide can make you drop since it affects the body's oxygen levels (too low). I have an alternative answer also, if you smell (sniff) too much coke (as in cocaine) you'll drop as in a possible OD.)

Comment: Excellent! Great explanation. Props!

Answer (score 0):

Is it . . .

> Water?

I show polar bears white
and I make you wanna try.

> The first thing I thought of was snow. So hang on to that thought for now.

I make guys have to pee,
and girls have to pee too.

> Drinking water, of course. But not snow. If water were to freeze though, it would show the polar bears "white" which is snow.

I make celebrities look stupid
and I make normal people cool.

> Drinking water is a celebrity thing apparently? And we do it too, so we're also celebrities.

Part of me turns pancakes brown
and makes your champagne bubble.

> Water is a major factor in champagne. Pouring water on pancakes will darken their color. Syrup would be fine in this sense too, but syrup doesn't fit with the rest.

If you're mean to me I'll pop.
If you smell too much you'll drop.

> The popping part is a bubble, since water bubbles. Smelling water leads to drowning, so the "drop" would be either death or (if you are rescued in time) fainting/passing out.

Comment: Interesting guess! You got close!